# How restrict Anonymous users from creating accounts

Tags: users

I am building my first site in Drupal(7), and I would like to restrict unloged users from creating user accounts, so how can I disable new account creating from `{mysiteName}/user?`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answer, if the answer is helpful for you consider selecting it as the correct answer. There is a checkmark below the answer ratings. ▲ 4 ▼ √

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `sitename.com/admin/config/people/accounts`

Scroll down to find **REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION**

Select appropriate option in **Who can register accounts?** field

[image]